# Calling a method and all the associated variables from another class - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, oop

I am trying to organise my code into classes that make sense, so I created a `FileIOManagement` class that I want to handle all the reading from text files etc.  Currently, the methods I use to read files live in the GUI class that displays the data, but I want to be able to separate GUI and other logic.

This is the code for my current FileIOManagement class:

```
package playingwithswing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIOManagement {

     private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     private ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     private ArrayList<String> semesterList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> moderatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> programList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> majorList = new ArrayList<String>();


     public FileIOManagement(){
         readTextFile();
     }

      private void readTextFile(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));

             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scan.nextLine();            
             String[] tokens = line.split("~");
             String course = tokens[0].trim();
             String examiner = tokens[1].trim();
             String moderator = tokens[2].trim();
             String semester = tokens[3].trim();
             String program = tokens[4].trim();
             String major = tokens[5].trim();


             courseList.add(course);
             semesterList.add(semester);
             nameList.add(examiner);
             moderatorList.add(moderator);
             programList.add(program);
             majorList.add(major);
             HashSet hs = new HashSet();
             hs.addAll(nameList);
             nameList.clear();
             nameList.addAll(hs);
             Collections.sort(nameList);

         }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }



}
```

This is the class that I want to be able to show the data from the file reading that is done by the `FileIOManagement` class.  I have commented out the lines of code, I have moved into the `FileIOManagement` class:

```
package playingwithswing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class ReportGUI extends JFrame{
    //Fields
    private JButton viewAllReports = new JButton("View All Program Details");
    private JButton viewPrograms = new JButton("View Programs and Majors Associated with this course"); 
    private JButton viewTaughtCourses = new JButton("View Courses this Examiner Teaches"); 
    private JLabel courseLabel = new JLabel("Select a Course: ");
    private JLabel examinerLabel = new JLabel("Select an Examiner: "); 
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2,4,4));  
    private FileIOManagement fileWork = new FileIOManagement();
//    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
//    private ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
//    private ArrayList<String> semesterList = new ArrayList<String>();
//    private ArrayList<String> moderatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
//    private ArrayList<String> programList = new ArrayList<String>();
//    private ArrayList<String> majorList = new ArrayList<String>();





     public ReportGUI(){   
            reportInterface();

            allReportsBtn();     
//            examinnerFileRead();
           // courseFileRead();
            comboBoxes();
     }        

//   private void examinnerFileRead(){
//         try{
//             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));
//             
//             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
//             String line = scan.nextLine();            
//             String[] tokens = line.split("~");
//             String course = tokens[0].trim();
//             String examiner = tokens[1].trim();
//             String moderator = tokens[2].trim();
//             String semester = tokens[3].trim();
//             String program = tokens[4].trim();
//             String major = tokens[5].trim();
//          
//
//             courseList.add(course);
//             semesterList.add(semester);
//             nameList.add(examiner);
//             moderatorList.add(moderator);
//             programList.add(program);
//             majorList.add(major);
//             HashSet hs = new HashSet();
//             hs.addAll(nameList);
//             nameList.clear();
//             nameList.addAll(hs);
//             Collections.sort(nameList);
//           //  nameList.add(moderator);
//         }
//             scan.close();
//         }
//         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
//             e.printStackTrace();
//         }
//     }
//      private void courseFileRead(){
//         try{
//             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));
//            
//             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
//                 courseList.add(scan.nextLine());
//             }
//             scan.close();
//         }
//         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
//             e.printStackTrace();
//         }
//     }

    private void reportInterface(){         
          setTitle("Choose Report Specifications");                   
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
          add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          setSize(650,200);
          setVisible(true);    
          setResizable(false);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
    private void allReportsBtn(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(70, 50, 70, 25));
        panel.add(viewAllReports);        
        viewAllReports.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){               
                new AllDataGUI();
            }
        });         
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }       
    private void comboBoxes(){     

        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
        String[] comboBox1Array = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
        panel.add(examinerLabel);
        panel.add(comboBox1);          
        panel.add(viewTaughtCourses);
         viewTaughtCourses.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewCourseGUI();
            }
        });  
         String[] comboBox2Array = courseList.toArray(new String[courseList.size()]);
         JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox(comboBox2Array);
         panel.add(courseLabel);         
         panel.add(comboBox2); 
         panel.add(viewPrograms);
         viewPrograms.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewProgramGUI();             
            }
        });  
         add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

    }   

}
```

What would be the best object oriented focused method to go about doing this?

EDIT:  I have tried setters and getters with no luck... This is driving me nuts.

```
package playingwithswing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class ReportGUI extends JFrame {
    //Fields
    private JButton viewAllReports = new JButton("View All Program Details");
    private JButton viewPrograms = new JButton("View Programs and Majors Associated with this course"); 
    private JButton viewTaughtCourses = new JButton("View Courses this Examiner Teaches"); 
    private JLabel courseLabel = new JLabel("Select a Course: ");
    private JLabel examinerLabel = new JLabel("Select an Examiner: "); 
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2,4,4)); 
    private FileIOManagement fileInformation;
    private ArrayList<FileIOManagement> nameList;
    private ArrayList<FileIOManagement> courseList;   


    private void setNameList(ArrayList<FileIOManagement> names){
        nameList = names;
    }    
    private ArrayList<FileIOManagement> getNameList(){
        return nameList;
    }
    private void setCourseList(ArrayList<FileIOManagement> courses){
        courseList = courses;
    }    
    private ArrayList<FileIOManagement> getCourseList(){
        return courseList;
    }
    private void setFileIOManagement(FileIOManagement fileObj){
        fileInformation = fileObj;
    }
    private FileIOManagement getFileInformation(){
        return fileInformation;
    }


    private String obtainFileList(){
        ArrayList<String> nameList = this.getFileInformation().obtainNamesForGUI();
        ArrayList<String> courseList = this.getFileInformation().obtainCoursesForGUI();
        return nameList.get(0);
    }

    public ReportGUI(){
        reportInterface();            
            allReportsBtn();     
            //fileRead();
            comboBoxes();
    }

     public ReportGUI(ArrayList<FileIOManagement> nameList, ArrayList<FileIOManagement> courseList){   

            setNameList(nameList);
            setCourseList(courseList);
            reportInterface();            
            allReportsBtn();     
            //fileRead();
            comboBoxes();
     }        

//   private void fileRead(){
//         try{
//             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));
//             
//             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
//             String line = scan.nextLine();            
//             String[] tokens = line.split("~");
//             String course = tokens[0].trim();
//             String examiner = tokens[1].trim();
//             String moderator = tokens[2].trim();
//             String semester = tokens[3].trim();
//             String program = tokens[4].trim();
//             String major = tokens[5].trim();
//          
//
//             courseList.add(course);
//             semesterList.add(semester);
//             nameList.add(examiner);
//             moderatorList.add(moderator);
//             programList.add(program);
//             majorList.add(major);
//             HashSet hs = new HashSet();
//             hs.addAll(nameList);
//             nameList.clear();
//             nameList.addAll(hs);
//             Collections.sort(nameList);
//           //  nameList.add(moderator);
//         }
//             scan.close();
//         }
//         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
//             e.printStackTrace();
//         }
//     }


    private void reportInterface(){         
          setTitle("Choose Report Specifications");                   
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
          add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          setSize(650,200);
          setVisible(true);    
          setResizable(false);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
    private void allReportsBtn(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(70, 50, 70, 25));
        panel.add(viewAllReports);        
        viewAllReports.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){               
                new AllDataGUI();
            }
        });         
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }       
    private void comboBoxes(){     

        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
       String[] comboBox1Array = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
        panel.add(examinerLabel);
        panel.add(comboBox1);          
        panel.add(viewTaughtCourses);
         viewTaughtCourses.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewCourseGUI();
            }
        });  
         String[] comboBox2Array = courseList.toArray(new String[courseList.size()]);
         JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox(comboBox2Array);
         panel.add(courseLabel);         
         panel.add(comboBox2); 
         panel.add(viewPrograms);
         viewPrograms.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewProgramGUI();             
            }
        });  
         add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

    }   

}
```

And the FIO class:

```
package playingwithswing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIOManagement {

     private ArrayList<String> nameList;// = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     private ArrayList<String> courseList;// = new ArrayList<String>(); 
//     private ArrayList<String> semesterList = new ArrayList<String>();
//     private ArrayList<String> moderatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
//     private ArrayList<String> programList = new ArrayList<String>();
//     private ArrayList<String> majorList = new ArrayList<String>();


     public ArrayList<String> obtainNamesForGUI(){
         ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
         return nameList;
     }
     public ArrayList<String> obtainCoursesForGUI(){
         ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();
         return courseList;
     }


//    private ArrayList<String> getNameList(){
//        return nameList;
//    }
//    
//    private ArrayList<String> getCourseList(){
//        return courseList;
//    }

     public FileIOManagement(){
         readTextFile();

     }

      private void readTextFile(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));

             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scan.nextLine();            
             String[] tokens = line.split("~");
             String course = tokens[0].trim();
             String examiner = tokens[1].trim();
             String moderator = tokens[2].trim();
             String semester = tokens[3].trim();
             String program = tokens[4].trim();
             String major = tokens[5].trim();


             courseList.add(course);
             //semesterList.add(semester);
             nameList.add(examiner);
            // moderatorList.add(moderator);
            // programList.add(program);
            // majorList.add(major);
             HashSet hs = new HashSet();
             hs.addAll(nameList);
             nameList.clear();
             nameList.addAll(hs);
             Collections.sort(nameList);

         }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }



}
```

Comment: `"What would be the best object oriented focused method to go about doing this?"` -- sorry, to go about doing what, specifically?

Comment: Calling the method from the other class so the code will work like it does when the method is in the original class.

Comment: getter and setter the classical method

Comment: get and set the method?  Can you please show me an example?

Comment: Read up on design patterns such as the Model View Controller design.

Comment: It is better to be working out Java 101 things like using objects and their members (methods and attributes) in command line apps. rather than apps. with a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you only need to add get methods inside your FileIOManagement class. Then you will be able to access the array lists inside FileIOManagement by calling the methods associated with the fileWork variable, which is a FileIOManagement object.

FileIOManagement class:

```
package playingwithswing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIOManagement {

 private ArrayList<String> nameList; 
 private ArrayList<String> courseList; 
 private ArrayList<String> semesterList;
 private ArrayList<String> moderatorList;
 private ArrayList<String> programList;
 private ArrayList<String> majorList;


 public FileIOManagement(){
     nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     courseList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     semesterList = new ArrayList<String>();
     moderatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
     programList = new ArrayList<String>();
     majorList = new ArrayList<String>();
     readTextFile();      
 }

 public ArrayList<String> getNameList() {return nameList;}
 public ArrayList<String> getCourseList() {return nameList;}
 public ArrayList<String> getSemesterList() {return nameList;}
 public ArrayList<String> getModeratorList() {return nameList;}
 public ArrayList<String> getProgramList() {return nameList;}
 public ArrayList<String> getMajorList() {return nameList;}

  private void readTextFile(){
     try{
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));

         while(scan.hasNextLine()){
         String line = scan.nextLine();            
         String[] tokens = line.split("~");
         String course = tokens[0].trim();
         String examiner = tokens[1].trim();
         String moderator = tokens[2].trim();
         String semester = tokens[3].trim();
         String program = tokens[4].trim();
         String major = tokens[5].trim();


         courseList.add(course);
         semesterList.add(semester);
         nameList.add(examiner);
         moderatorList.add(moderator);
         programList.add(program);
         majorList.add(major);
         HashSet hs = new HashSet();
         hs.addAll(nameList);
         nameList.clear();
         nameList.addAll(hs);
         Collections.sort(nameList);

     }
         scan.close();
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

ReportGUI class:

```
package playingwithswing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class ReportGUI extends JFrame{
    //Fields
    private JButton viewAllReports = new JButton("View All Program Details");
    private JButton viewPrograms = new JButton("View Programs and Majors Associated    with this course"); 
    private JButton viewTaughtCourses = new JButton("View Courses this Examiner Teaches"); 
    private JLabel courseLabel = new JLabel("Select a Course: ");
    private JLabel examinerLabel = new JLabel("Select an Examiner: "); 
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2,4,4));  
    private FileIOManagement fileWork;



 public ReportGUI(){  
        fileWork = new FileIOManagement();
        reportInterface();

        allReportsBtn();     
        examinnerFileRead();
        courseFileRead();
        comboBoxes();
 }        


private void reportInterface(){         
      setTitle("Choose Report Specifications");                   
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
      add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setSize(650,200);
      setVisible(true);    
      setResizable(false);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
private void allReportsBtn(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(70, 50, 70, 25));
    panel.add(viewAllReports);        
    viewAllReports.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){               
            //new AllDataGUI();
        }
    });         
    add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
}       
private void comboBoxes(){     

    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
    String[] comboBox1Array = fileWork.getNameList().toArray(
            new String[fileWork.getNameList().size()]);
    JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
    panel.add(examinerLabel);
    panel.add(comboBox1);          
    panel.add(viewTaughtCourses);
     viewTaughtCourses.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
             //new ViewCourseGUI();
        }
    });  
     String[] comboBox2Array = fileWork.getCourseList().toArray(
             new String[fileWork.getCourseList().size()]);
     JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox(comboBox2Array);
     panel.add(courseLabel);         
     panel.add(comboBox2); 
     panel.add(viewPrograms);
     viewPrograms.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
             //new ViewProgramGUI();             
        }
    });  
     add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

}   

}
```